# Можно ли скрыть айпи адрес входящего соединения?

Tags: java, debian, iptables

Я использую debian 9. У меня работает java-сервер, на который подключаются клиенты. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы сервер не мог узнать настоящие айпи адреса клиентов. Это нужно для безопасности.

Было бы неплохо, если бы для сервера айпи адреса клиентов заменялись на какой-нибудь локальный айпи, например, 127.0.0.1.

Возможно такое можно сделать с помощью iptables или настроек ядра?

Comment: Перед сервером прокси с подменой адресов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение через iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.1
```

Где `--dport 80` - порт локального сервера, а `192.168.2.1` "поддельный" айпи адрес клиентов.